# uncheckable items in CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, list, checkedlistbox

In .NET framework, is it possible to set some of the items in the `CheckedListBox` as "uncheckable" ? I don't want to allow user to check the same items again and add them to a another existing list.

I hope I am clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would set those items as "Indeterminate" in code, and then overwrite the "NewValue" property from the ItemCheck event when the user attempts to check/uncheck them:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Can't check me", CheckState.Indeterminate);
}

private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
    {
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
    }
}
```

The "Can't check me" item in the CheckedListBox can't be modified, because every time the user tries to check/uncheck it, the event handler changes it back. You don't even see the UI update accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Matt's code is good.

Yet, why have an item in the checkedlistbox and not let it be selected?
I mean why have that item in the list.

Comment: Actuall what I am thinking is something like this: We have two lists. User can select and add things from list one to list two. BUT, I don't want to let the user add the same item to the second list for a second time. In other words, list 2 should consist of uniq elements of list1.

Comment: Even if you cannot think of a reason why YOU would want an uncheckable item in a CheckedListBox, can you not imagine that somewhere, sometime, someone has a good reason for it? Some people prefer to conform. Some people prefer to think outside of the box. Every time someone says "Why would you want to do that?" I can always think of reasons why they might.